# What items and augments implicitly ignore armor?

Tags: invisible-inc

I've found that the [HoloCircuit Overloaders augment](http://invisibleinc.wikia.com/wiki/Augments) seems to ignore armor, even though its description doesn't explicitly say so:

> Knock out all enemies in a small area around this agent.

What other items or augments are there that ignore armor, but don't explicitly say so?

Comment: My suspicion is that armor only matters for weapon attacks, but I haven't done enough to be sure of this.

Answer (score 2):

On my current endless run (day 10 atm) you often come across enemies with armor lvl3, or the omni-soldiers with armor equal to their firewalls. Methods to deal with very high armor are very wanted.

Right now, I've figured out these tactics to knock out  very-high-armor enemies.

1. **Holocircuit augment** (with a cloak item, or a stim+cloak aug)
2. **Shock traps** (put on door, have enemy open door)
3. **Flash grenades** (ignore armor, not in the description, AOE but single use)
4. Combination of **Penetrating Scanner** (can stack), **Higher level** Neural Disruptors or Shock **Disruptors** (each level adds an armor penetrating)
5. If it's **firewall armor: EMP** to take down (watch out for magnetic fortification, it only lowers 2) then conventional means.